# POST array of values to java servlet

Tags: java, arrays, post

I want to place the following form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MPK[]" value="x" class="MPK"/>
<input type="hidden" name="MPK[]" value="y" class="MPK"/>
<input type="hidden" name="MPK[]" value="z" class="MPK"/>
...
```

and POST it to servlet or JSP page. 
How to get values of these inputs in one array in servlet?

```
request.getParameterValues("MPK");
```

doesn't work even if i remove [] from names.

Comment: why are you using "input hidden" ? Please post the code of the `<form>`

Comment: how do you read the values in you Servlet/JSP? Are you trying with `getParameter()` or `getParameterValues()` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to get the values from array by parsing it.

```
String[] mpk;

mpk= request.getParameterValues("mpk");
for(int i = 0; i < mpk.length; i++)
{
System.out.println(mpk[i]);
}
```

Comment: Hi i have posted the values but it give me error java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 1):

Remove "[]" from you parameter name.
e.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="MPK" value="x" class="MPK"/>
```